# SQL: Find duplicates and for each duplicate group assign value of first duplicate of that group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates, grouping

I have the results in the top table.  I would like the results in the bottom table.

[image]

Using an SQL query on the table above, I would like to find groups of duplicates (where the values in all columns except Id and Category are identical) and from that create a result that has for each entry the lowest Id from its group of duplicates and the (unmodified) Category from the original table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window function `min` can be used here:

```
select min(id) over (partition by first_name, last_name, company) id,
    category
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, that works and is a simpler expression than what I expected.